# Exercise with derivation of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:A\to B$ be an injective homomorphism of integral domains, where $A$ is integrally closed. Assume also that $ 
B$ and its integral closure, $\bar B$, are finitely generated $A$-modules. Show that if $\Omega_{B/A}=0$, then $B=\bar B$ (the $A$-module $\Omega_{B/A}$ is the universal derivation).

I posted the whole text to give a context, but I'm actually interested in knowing how can I use that the universal derivation is zero in the case that $B$ is not an algebra over a field. I can't use Zariski tangent space and the related notions, but I don't have any ideas. Thanks for any hint